# Chaining Requests using Python and Aiohttp

Tags: python, asynchronous, async-await, aiohttp

I am new to asynchronous programming in python, have been working on a script using aiohttp that fetches data from a get request and passes a specific  variable from the response onto another post request. A sample of what I have tried is below:

```
async def fetch1(url):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get(url) as resp:      # First hit to the url 
            data = resp.json()                    # Grab response
            return await fetch2(data['uuid'])     # Pass uuid to the second function for post request

async def fetch2(id):
    url2 = "http://httpbin.org/post"
    params = {'id': id}
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.post(url2,data=params) as resp:
            return await resp.json()


async def main():
    url = 'http://httpbin.org/uuid'
    data = await fetch1(url)


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

When I execute the script, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\benchmark.py", line 27, in <module>
   loop.run_until_complete(main())
  File "C:\ProgramFiles\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.2288.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 616, in run_until_complete
  return future.result()
  File ".\benchmark.py", line 22, in main
   data = await fetch1(url)
  File ".\benchmark.py", line 10, in fetch1
   return fetch2(data['uuid'])
TypeError: 'coroutine' object is not subscriptable
sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'ClientResponse.json' was never awaited
```

I know that the coroutine is a generator, but how do I go ahead, any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error says `coroutine 'ClientResponse.json' was never awaited` which means it must have an `await` before the json part. This is because you are using an async function.

```py
async def fetch1(url):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get(url) as resp:      # First hit to the url 
            data = await resp.json()                    # Grab response
            return await fetch2(data['uuid'])     # Pass uuid to the second function for post request

async def fetch2(id):
    url2 = "http://httpbin.org/post"
    params = {'id': id}
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.post(url2,data=params) as resp:
            return await resp.json()


async def main():
    url = 'http://httpbin.org/uuid'
    data = await fetch1(url)


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Comment: but is this an optimal way to do something like this? just wanted to know if it follows async behaviour

Comment: @CharlieChap Well you are doing an async request so it  looks fine. You might want to post in https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ for opinions on your code.